How do you add a Certification Symbol to a resume?
I need a symbol for certifications next to it's link.
I have managed to do so for linkedIn, GitHub, etc.
Using the following code:
\begin{center}
    {\Huge \scshape \color{blue} Some Name} \\ \vspace{5pt}
    {\small \raisebox{-0.2\height}\faPhone\ Some Phone number \hspace{2pt} | \hspace{2pt}
    \href{mailto:Some mailid}{\raisebox{-0.2\height}\faEnvelope\ 
    \underline{Some mailid}} \hspace{2pt} | \hspace{2pt}
    \href{Some Link}{\raisebox{-0.2\height}\faLinkedin\ \underline{LinkedIn}} \hspace{2pt} | \hspace{2pt}
    \href{Some Link}{\raisebox{-0.2\height}\faGithub\ 
    \underline{Github}} \hspace{2pt} | \hspace{2pt}
    \href{Some Link}{\raisebox{-0.2\height}\underline{LinkedIn}}}
    \vspace{-8pt}
\end{center}


But I need this symbol in code:


\faCertificate

You seem to use the fontawesome package: you can find all available symbols along with the relevant commands in in the package documentation.
